# Approximate standard error of the maximum likelihood estimate

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, standard-error

> **Question**: Suppose that $X$ is a discrete random variable with :
> \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
>  \hline
>          X &   0 &  1 &   2 &  3\\ \hline
>          \mathbb P(X=x) &\frac{2}{3}\theta &\frac{1}{3}\theta &\frac{2}{3}(1-\theta) &\frac{1}{3}(1-\theta) \\ \hline
> \end{array}
> Where $0\leq\theta\leq1$ is a parameter. The following $10$ independent observations were taken from such a distribution: $\{3,0,2,1,3,2,1,0,2,1\}$
>
> (a) Find the method of moments estimate of $\theta$.
> (b) Find an approximate standard error for your estimate.
> (c) What is the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$ ?
> (d) What is an approximate standard error of the maximum likelihood estimate?

I figure out (a+b), $\theta$ using method of moment estimate and got, $\bar\theta=\frac{7}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(\bar{X})$ and $$Var(\bar\theta)=-\frac{1}{10}\theta^2+\frac{1}{10}\theta+\frac{1}{180}$$
Using the above information and with Log Likelihood function I also manage to find out (c), $MSE_{\bar{\theta}}=\frac{1}{2}$

for (d), I have no idea. What I only know that is,
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar{\theta}-\theta_0)⟶N\left(0,\frac{1}{I(\theta_0)}\right)\text{ Asymptotic normality of MLE}$$
But I really don't understand it truly, and how to solve (d) (Using it or other way)?

Comment: sorry but in your pmf if $\theta=1$ the total probability is 2

Comment: Sorry there were some typos, I fixed those @tommik

Answer (score 0):

(a)

Your MoM estimator doesn't look right. In fact, being

$$\mu=\frac{\theta}{3}+\frac{4}{3}(1-\theta)+ (1-\theta)=\frac{7}{3}-2\theta$$

You get

$$\hat{\theta}_{MM}=\Bigg[\frac{7}{3}-\overline{X}_{10}\Bigg]\frac{1}{2}$$

That is

$$\hat{\theta}_{\text{estimate}}=\frac{5}{12}$$

(b)

Variance of MoM estimator looks fine, anyway  the question is not asking MSE but just an estimation of [standard error](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) , that is standard deviation of the statistic sample distribution: $\approx 0.173$

(c) and (d): do the same procedure with ML estimation. Given that you know the asymptotic distribution of MLE I think it is not difficult for you to conclude.

Comment: I actually know the asymptotic distribution, but I didn't get it truly/intuitively @tommik. Could you give some light on it? I really want to understand it. After that, I will accept your answer and close this thread.